# uniform distribution mean and variance

Tags: probability

Given that $X$ has a discrete uniform distribution that can have values from $-2$ to $+2$, calculate

A)the number of possible values of $X,n$

B) mean

C) variance

i know X can be -2 ,-1,0,1,2 but what about n and how do u calculate mean and variance for different n?

Comment: i m stuck on the -2 to +2 part. i dont know how to proceed

Comment: can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given that $X$ has a discrete uniform distribution that can have values from $-2$ to $+2$, calculate

This is unclear, but if you interpret it to mean *the integer values from* $-2$ *to* $2$, that is $X\sim[-2;2]\cap\Bbb N$, then indeed...

> A)the number of possible values of $X,n$

We have $n=\lvert\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}\rvert$.   Just count the elements in the set.

> B) mean

By the definition: $\mathsf E(X)= \mathop{\sum\qquad}\limits_{x\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}} x\,\mathsf P(X=x)$

Do you know the probability mass function for a *discrete uniform* distribution?   Then you can find it by first principles.   Its good to practice.

However, if you prefer, you may use a *known formula* for the mean of a *discrete uniform distribution*? (Do you know it? You can research it in Ms. Wikipeadia's library, or just ask Mr. Google for directions, if you like.)

> C) variance

By the definition: $\mathsf {Var}(X)= \mathop{\sum\qquad}\limits_{x\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}} (x-\mathsf E(X))^2\,\mathsf P(X=x)$

Again, calculate this from first principles or use the known formula.

Comment: that certainly helps  
thanks